# T4CPreparedStatement instance not releasing memory related to bind parameters,causing memory leak over time

Tags: jdbc, memory-leaks, prepared-statement, oracle12c, apache-commons-dbcp

Using DBCP2 connection pool in a spring webapp with Oracle 12c r1 as the backend database with OJDBC8.jar, turned on the poolpreparedstatement feature of dbcp2 to reduce parsing on the database side.

DBCP2 configuration:

```
String data = property.getProperty(Constants.DATABASE_USERNAME);
        if( data != null && data.isEmpty() == false )
            setUsername(data);
        setPassword(password);

        data = property.getProperty(Constants.DATABASE_INITIAL_SIZE);
        if( data != null && data.isEmpty() == false )
            setInitialSize(Integer.parseInt(data));
        else
            setInitialSize(8);

        data = property.getProperty(Constants.DATABASE_MAX_ACTIVE);
        if( data != null && data.isEmpty() == false )
            setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(data));
        else
            setMaxTotal(64);

        this.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);
        this.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(120);
```

When setting the number of prepared statements to pool parameter to something >100 and making batch inserts using BatchSqlUpdate into table M1(eg), after certain time the application crashes with javaOutofMemory: java heap exception.

Table desc:

```
c1            NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
c2            NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
c3            NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
c4            NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
c5            NUMBER(38)     
c6            NUMBER(38)     
c7            RAW(2000 BYTE) 
c8            RAW(2000 BYTE) 
c9            BLOB
```

Looked at v$sql_shared-cursor view to see the version_count. But there only 3 version counts due to bind mismatch in maxlength in one of the 3 binary datatype columns. No high version count so moved on,

Looked at the heap dump to find that oracle.T4CPreparedStatement is retaining large amounts of memory in:

this     - value: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement #143
 -> parameterStream     - class: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement, value: java.io.InputStream[][] #2---->THIS HOLDS A LOT OF MEMORY

The T4CPreparedStatement instance is for the following query:
Query fired as seen in v$sql_area and the heapdump:

```
Insert into M1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9) values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9)
```

Infact all the instance which retain high memory are for the exact same insert prepared statement on table M1.

Another thing I noticed is the number of instance of oracleT4CPrepared Statement & PooledPreparedStatement of dbcp2 are matching and were 631 instances, even though I had set the maxlimit as 120

Please note that this doesn't happen always consistently,sometimes the T4CPreparedStatement instances are removed from memory as seen in consecutive heap dumps and application continues to stay running.

How can I free the memory the oracle preparedstatement is holding?